# How can I highlight or somehow differentiate between folds and non folded lines?

Tags: folding

I have vim folds and love the functionality, but I want to be able to see what text is included in the fold when I open it.

Is there anything I can include in my vimrc to have vim specifically color or somehow differentiate that text is within a fold, even when the fold is open?

Thanks!

Comment: See `:h 'foldcolumn'`

Comment: shameless plug: https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami